# Is it possible to derive the command line arguments for mondoarchive after running it manually?

Tags: linux, backup

I've recently found out about and then run mondoarchive for the first time on a server, I would like to make this backup job in to a cron job to run regular backups.

After running the backup I checked the log file, which is pretty massive, after scanning through it, I didn't see what I was hoping to find, I did a quick Google search, but I didn't find much that was helpful. It may be that what I am trying to find isn't there, in which case that's fine, I'll have to figure out all the command line arguments for myself.

Basically, I was wondering whether mondoarchive can tell me what command line flags would be needed to reproduce the backup job I have configured during the manual startup procedure, rather than having to put them all together myself, so that I can easy run the same job again via cron/script.

I am running mondo-3.2.0 on CentOS 6, I would have added the tag mondoarchive or something similar, but I don't have the rep to do so.

===

EDIT

On the recommendation of the comments I checked the /proc/PID/cmdline file contents (I watched it as I ran the command) and that never changed (it always showed mondoarchive). I then tried running "ps -ef | grep mondo" this showed mondoarchive spawned a number of child processes, some were mindi jobs, others were afio & gzip, but I don't have a command I could run from a script still. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Not really using mondoarchive, but if your shell has history support you *might* still find that cmd with all the args in the shell history.

Comment: Also don't know mondoarchive but if it's currently running its in /proc/(PID)/cmdline